# Complex Fourier series expansion error (Python)

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I was trying to expand an impulse function via expansion into complex Fourier series. See the following almost working example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tp = 1
N = 1000
w = 0.05
t = np.linspace(-Tp/2, Tp/2, N)
dt = Tp/N

xp = np.zeros(N)
xp[abs(t) <= w*Tp] = 1
xp = xp + 0.0*(np.random.rand(N)-0.5)

def cn(x, t, dt, Tp, n):
    return np.trapz(x*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*n*t/Tp),dx=dt)*1/Tp

def c(x, t, dt, Tp, N):
    return [cn(x, t, dt, Tp, i) for i in range(-N,N)]

def rek_c(x, t, dt, Tp, N):
    _c=c(x, t, dt, Tp, N)
    out=np.zeros(len(x),dtype='complex')
    for i in range(-N,N):
        out += _c[N+i]*np.exp(1j*2*np.pi*(i)*t/Tp)
    return out

plt.plot(t, xp)
plt.plot(t, rek_c(xp, t, dt, Tp,50 ), 'r')
plt.show()
```

The example above produces
[image]

as expected. Yet something really strange happens when the expansion goes towards 1000 elements. So typing `plt.plot(t, rek_c(xp, t, dt, Tp, 1000 ), 'r')` produces this (obviously wrong) plot:
[image]

Why? And how do I correct that?

Comment: I'm guessing some rounding error is exacerbated when the number of points increases. Maybe some reorganizing of the equations can avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with your code a bit, I found out the following:

If increase N in the header you can handle more elements N (input parameter of rek_c). So

```
K=N-1
plt.plot(t, rek_c(xp, t, dt, Tp,K ), 'r')
```

will give you the last acceptable result, while

```
K=N
plt.plot(t, rek_c(xp, t, dt, Tp,K ), 'r')
```

will give the first wrong result.

Let us call the last parameter in the rek_c command K now, while N is the number of meshpoints, defined in the header.
I think what happens is, that you can not expland in a higher number of frequencies K than your input has meshpoints N. The (complete) discrete Fourier transformation gives you 2N-1 frequencies. For K=N you expand in 2N frequencies, which istoo much then.

For a more detailed analysis, it is worth to have a look into [Nyquist frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency) (highest possible frequency for discrete data) and  [numpy.fft.fft](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft).

Comment: I just recognized, that I have some doubt about your algorithm. Maybe its worth crosschecking with numpy.fft.fft